# Bootstrap: multiple affix

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hava a structure like this:

```
-section1
  -sidebar1
  -content1
-section2
  -sidebar2
  -content2
```

and so on...

I want to use the affix plugin as on [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) but each sidebar should be "fixed" only as long i'm navigatint its section.

So if the user is viewing section1 sidebar1 should be fixed, when it scrolls down to section2 sidebar1 should be released and sidebar 2 should be fixed.

Something like that project https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed (see the fifth demos, stackoverflow doesn't let me link to jsfiddle without posting some code)

Comment: Does doing what's in that demo you linked (http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/769/) not work for you? Isn't that essentially what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes but i'm trying to do that with twitter bootstrap

Comment: What happens when you use this code in conjunction with bootstrap then? I don't see anything that would keep them from working together...